# hide page extension in url

Tags: asp.net

How can i hide page extension (for ex .aspx , .php) from url of the page

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should use IIS URL Rewriter module.
http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/460/using-the-url-rewrite-module/

Answer (score 2):

Here you have a good article about how to achive friendly urls on asp net

http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/02/26/tip-trick-url-rewriting-with-asp-net.aspx

It covers 4 options

- Use Request.PathInfo Parameters Instead of QueryStrings
- Using an HttpModule to Perform URL Rewriting
- Using an HttpModule to Perform Extension-Less URL Rewriting with IIS7
- ISAPIRewrite to enable Extension-less URL Rewriting for IIS5 and IIS6

Answer (score 0):

If you have IIS6 server, you have to do few modification in order to ASP.NET ISAPI catch extension-less url. In IIS7, use Integrated pipeline application pool. Then with some URL rewriter or mapper (ASP.NET Routing, UrlRewriting.NET,...) configure your urls to physical files or MVC controller/action.